# Converting Access IIF to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, iif

Having issues converting **IIf(VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP="AG","AG","OT") AS DEPT**, to Oracle

```
Select
VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.year,
VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.LOC,
VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.CAT,
VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.TY,
(case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end) as DEPT,
VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.SRCE,
Sum(VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.EXPEND * 0.001) As EXP
From
VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY
GROUP BY VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.year, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.LOC, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.CAT, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.TY, (case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end) as DEPT, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.SRCE
HAVING (((Sum(VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.EXPEND * 0.001)))<>0);
```

The query tells me that i have an error, seems trivial at this point

```
Error at Command Line:11 Column:169
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: dont use oracle and usually only work with access, does the IIF statement work the same way

Comment: Select
    VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.year,
    VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.LOC,
    VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.CAT,
    VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.TY,
    (case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end) as DEPT,
    VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.SRCE,
    Sum(VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.EXPEND * 0.001) As EXP
    From
    VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY
    GROUP BY VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.year, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.LOC, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.CAT, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.TY, (case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end) as DEPT, VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.SRCE
    HAVING (((Sum(VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.EXPEND * 0.001)))<>0);

Comment: Now it tells me that SQL command not ended properly????

Comment: Get rid of the `AS DEPT` in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue is the one in your text, then it is easy.  Use `case` (which is ANSI standard):

```
(case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end) as DEPT
```

Here is a full version of your query:

```
Select v.year, v.LOC, v.CAT, v.TY,
       (case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end) as DEPT
       v.SRCE,
       Sum(v.EXPEND * 0.001) As EXP
From VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY v
GROUP BY v.year, v.LOC, v.CAT, v.TY,
         (case when VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP = 'AG' then 'AG' else 'OT' end), v.SRCE
HAVING Sum(v.EXPEND * 0.001) <> 0;
```

I have simplified it by using table aliases.  And I removed the `as DEPT` from the `group by` clause.  And, I replaced the double quotes strings with single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DECODE() or better CASE WHEN

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
IIf(VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP="AG","AG","OT")
```

with

```
CASE WHEN VW_GE_ALL_YEARQRY.DEP='AG' THEN 'AG' ELSE 'OT' END
```

Share and enjoy.